# web page print button and settings

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I'm wondering if anyone has had any experience modifying print settings via a web page. My overall goal would be to setup a print button on a web page

```
<a href="javascript:window.print()">Print This Page</a>
```

And at the same time modify the users print settings to print the page from a landscape view. Input on if this is even possibly, or other suggestions would be appreciated. Modifying the page layout isn't really an option. I thought about using a separate style sheet for the printing page but that doesn't help with what I'm actually printing.

Comment: At most you can influence output by offering different style sheets for portrait/landscape, but your control over the printing process is limited to triggering the print process. After that it's completely up to the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For security reasons your JavaScript would not have have access to the print setup page.

Comment: I assumed so, just thought I would ask. Thanks for your input!